# listen to iframe process using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, addeventlistener

in my index there is 2 elements:

iframe - that submited using jquery from the index page and make a process.

progressbar - that should show me the progress of the iframe.

*i'm using bootstrap progressbar

**my problem is that i'm getting only the iframe loaded content and not the process so i cant know in which step the process is so i just can make the progress bar jump from 0% to 100%**

this is the html in the iframe:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="file_name" />
   <input type="text" name="user_id" />
   <input type="submit" name="btnUpload" value="submit" />
</form>
```

this is the jquery in the index page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
   var fileName = "test";
   var userID   = 123;
   $("#progress_iframe").contents().find("#file_name").val("fileName");
   $("#progress_iframe").contents().find("#user_id").val("userID");

   $("#progress_iframe").contents().find("#btnUpload").click();

   var interval = setInterval(function(){
      clearIntervar(interval);
      $("#progress_iframe").on('load',function(){
         //clear all text, keep an empty page that will get the process steps
         $(this).contents().find("form").remove();
         var text = $(this).contents().find("body").html();
         console.log(text);
      });
  },300);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by "process"? It looks to me like you wait for the iframe to load, then you remove the form and capture the remaining HTML (which should be nothing). If you want to send some kind of information from the iframe to its parent, use postMessage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

Comment: @TommyBrunn hi, i mean that the iframe receive UserID and FileName and make some changes with that file, i named it "process" cause i thought its the right name for the function i'm runing there.